# Login audit trail saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to customise the login audit trail results to see which of the employee has not used their NS license in a long time. However, the login audit trail shows me old entries of employees related to the roles they no longer have. Which additional filter I need to add to see login history pertaining to their current roles only?

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution depends on how you're search is set up.  But you should be able to incorporate a test/check for each line if "Role" (the role that was used to log in) matches "User : Role" (the role or roles currently available to the User).  If using summary add a summary criteria based on this and group results to show i.e. max dat of last log in grouped by User and Role.